Online PDF files become garbled upon opening, but downloaded file read OK
...HP Zbook 15-G6 with 48GB RAM. after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I can no longer read online PDF files from websites. They become garbled and blinking, seems overlapping with other PDF files in the back ground. However, I can read downloaded PDF file just fine. But this has become very inconvenient.
I keep my Ubuntu updated all the time. What could be causing this? What else should I try?
thanks a lot for any insight!

Thank you Talaat! Never thought of doing this. Yes, using Google Chrome everything looks fine now. Will reinstall Firefix.
